# what is the purpose of these props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-props

I'm trying to learn React from existing code, in the props section there is code like this

```
const {
  products,
  productDetail = {product:{}, productColor:[] },
  location={},
  history
 } = props
```

I don't understand on the productDetail and location, why is there {product:{}, productColor:[] }, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: default value if `undefined`

Comment: I think it is initialising the prop attribute if no value is passed

Comment: It's saying when `productDetail` is undefined, use this object `{product:{}, productColor:[] }`

Answer (score 0):

These are some default values for the specified props.
Looking at the provided example, I can say that `history` and `products` are required - when someone tries to render the component, he is obliged to procide that information.

However, the `productDetails` and `location` have default values so they are optional. The person trying to render this component may provide some values (if he wants to) but he is not obliged to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you have here is nothing more than a declaration of a variable (and assigning given by the object 'props').
Instead of the code posted one could write:

```
const productDetail = {product:{}, productColor:[] }
```

`productDetail` is a variable. A variable that happens to be an object.
This object contains two values, one named `product` that itself is defined as another object (hence why the '{}' is there) and `productColor` which is an array as the '[]' indicate.

Same with `location`. The "type" is array and the default value of that variable is an empty array.